# Apply Transparent Spatter Effect from Gallery on Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transparency, illustrator-effects

I have a basic square shape and I want to apply the SPATTER effect under Effects Gallery.
After applying the effect, I realized it adds a color to the SPATTER applied, while I would like that SPATTER to be Transparent (i.e. removing color from my shape).

See below photos.

INITIAL SHAPE:

[image]

AFTER SPATTER EFFECT

[image]

I would like to have that SPATTER effect transparent so my background can be visible.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the items listed under "Photoshop Effects" are applied **raster** effects and must have a background. They can't be created without the auto-generated background. So, what can one do? Create the effect where the use of white doesn't matter or means "transparent" -- such as on a mask.

Apply the effect to an **Opacity Mask** rather than the object itself.

- Select the rectangle
- `Edit > Copy`
- Click the `Make Mask` button on the **Transparency Panel**. 
  This will create a little mask thumbnail on the panel.
- Click the Mask Thumbnail on the **Transparency Panel**
- `Edit > Paste in Front` This will paste the rectangle in the same position on the *mask*
- Fill the pasted rectangle with the `Registration` color from the **Swatch Panel**. This is a **mask** so you want the rectangle to use all the colors. This is about the only time you'd ever use the `Registration` swatch for artwork.
- Now apply the `Spatter` effect to this rectangle on the mask.
- When applied, you may need to click the `Invert Mask` option on the **Transparency Panel**
- Click the artwork thumbnail on the **Transparency Panel** to go back to editing artwork.
- To edit the mask again in the future, you must click the *mask thumbnail* on the **Transparency Panel**

[image]

<sup>(Yellow added so transparency can be seen.)</sup>

Be aware: This is sill a **raster effect**. It is merely now on a mask rather on the object itself. You'll want to ensure the `Effect > Document Raster Effects Settings` is appropriately set before any output.