# How to color bitmap or non-editable objects in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

**Context**

I have a bitmap image in Illustrator (Effects > Rasterize > "Color Model: Bitmap", resulting in a black and white image). Alternatively, I have a brush or pattern, whose original I don't want to edit.

**Objective**

I want to change the appearance of the bitmap image (or pattern) by replacing the black with a color.

**My Method**

Create a fill in the desired color, make a mask, and move the black-and-white object to the mask layer.

This method works *fine*, and gives the desired appearance, but is a pain because it means the objects I actually want to work with are tucked away on masks that hard to access.

Is there a better way to colorize objects whose fill you don't have access to?

**Example**

I begin with a photograph (Image 1), which I have dithered with Effects > Rasterize > "Color Model: Bitmap", resulting in Image 2.

How can I color Image 2 to get Image 3?

[image]

Comment: Kind of need some visual reference. Offhand, no you can't alter the color of Bitmap Rasterization. That sort of defeats the Bitmap format. But you *can* colorize pattern fills.. which is really all the Bitmap filter is creating.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Why are you rasterizing an object if you want to change its fill?  That seems like a really weird thing to do.

Comment: @BillyKerr point well taken, I was being lazy with terms because I'd used Illustrator's _Rasterize..._ tool to get the bitmap image. Hopefully the edits and images help clarify what I mean. My real goal is to have bitmap in a different color than black

Comment: @Scott My wording was lazy, but see edits/comment to Billy: forget rasterize, I'm just trying to get bitmap in a different color. How can I colorize pattern fills? Or can I only do so by editing the underlying pattern?

Answer (score 1):

I **know** you mention this in the question. Detailed here for others.

I **do not** think there's a more efficient method. Really, I don't understand what more you'd be doing with the BMP image. What more *could* you do that does *not* work with an opacity mask applied? If the color shape matches the mask boundaries, editing would be essentially seamless.

AI simply only goes so far with raster images.

---

You can do this with a standard shape, filled with the color you want, then the BMP raster image as an **Opacity Mask** on that shape.

[image]

- Red filled rectangle.
- AI's Bitmap rasterization applied to png
- Copy/pasted BMP to the Opacity Mask for the color rectangle
- Tick the `Invert` option for the mask

Click the artwork thumbnail and change the fill color if you want a different color.

[image]

Same basic answer to [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/144875/apply-transparent-spatter-effect-from-gallery-on-illustrator) (which has a bit more detail.)

---

If you **group** the masked shape, you can even apply a *second* Opacity Mask (to the group) if necessary....

[image]

Comment: Oh my, I was just about to post the exact same answer. +1 for beating me to it!

Comment: @BillyKerr It's mentioned in the question.. so chances are this isn't anything Unrelated isn't already aware of. `:)` But I, know of no other method. I'd be curious if there is one, perhaps in a more bleeding edge version of AI than I prefer to use. `:)`

Comment: I think it would be exactly the same in AI CC.  Illustrator still has extremely limited bitmap editing, maybe better done in Photoshop ultimately.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I was hoping there might be a simple setting in Appearances, kind of like an extra fill, that recolors the object and doesn't require entering the mask to edit the bmp object. Even if that were possible, though, it prob would still be impossible to do a gradient like this :(

Comment: @Unrelated what type of gradient? You can apply the bitmap mask to a gradient mesh... or any group of objects.... so.... ?

Comment: @Scott no no, just saying that in the fake method I'm imagining it probably wouldn't be possible to do a gradient like you've done here, so this is prob the best (and only) method